Max Concurrent: 1 | Max # of Instances: 100 | Instances don't climb with number of requests
I finally got my FFmpeg working in Google Run, but for some reason, the number of instances is not scaling with the number of API requests sent. I'll send ten within a second, thinking there would be ten containers that would spin up. Has anyone seen this before?
https://preview.redd.it/gcp-run-max-concurrent-1-max-of-instances-100-instances-v0-wvej3crju9ld1.png?width=1058&format=png&auto=webp&s=72c4b11ab3b5c14ba4a4cba0d75e0421cbf2a39f

By default a Cloud Run instance is configured to handle up to 80 concurrent requests. If more requests are coming in, another instance will be started.
Also Google will try to keep the CPU utilization under 60% (over a 1 minute window) per instance. So you'll either have to put more load onto it, or lower the concurrency parameter.
